# Interactive shell script - Recursion too deep

Tags: shell, recursion, ksh

I am  making an interactive shell script in KSH but keep on getting 'recursion too deep' errors. There is no obvious pattern to it happening, other than the longer I use the script the more likely it gets.

I was previously advised this was because I did not build my menu system from a loop, but I have now done this using 'select'. Here is my menu:

```
clear

echo "\nDatabase:${HBDB} ClaimId:${CLAIM}  TxId:${TRANS}  SubsidyId:${SUBS}"
echo "Select your option"
PS3="Option?"

select opt in \
"Input new subsidy row" \
"Change transaction and subsidy id" \
"Change subsidy id only" \
"Show subsidy row details" \
"Exit"

do
    case $opt in
            "Input new subsidy row")

            followUp=$SUPPATH/menuSelect.sh

            echo 'Dropping temp table...mcc_ac_tmp_hb9880_${CLAIM}_${TRANS}_${SUBS} ' >> $OUTFILE1

            sql $HBDB <<_END_ | sed -n '/DROP/,$p' >> $OUTFILE1

            set autocommit on;
            \p\g
            set lockmode session where readlock = nolock;
            \p\g

            DROP TABLE mcc_ac_tmp_hb9880_${CLAIM}_${TRANS}_${SUBS}; 

            \p\g

_END_
            . $paramSet
            break
            ;;

            "Change transaction and subsidy id")
            followUp=$SUPPATH/menuSelect.sh

            . $transChange

            break
            ;;


            "Change subsidy id only")

            followUp=$SUPPATH/menuSelect.sh

            . $subsChange
            break
            ;;


            "Show subsidy row details")
            echo "Retrieving details..."
            followUp=$SUPPATH/menu1.sh

            sql $HBDB <<_END_ | grep '|'  

            set autocommit on;
            \p\g
            set lockmode session where readlock = nolock;
            \p\g

            select claim_id,rent_trans_id,rent_subsidy_id,from_date,pay_amt
            from hbrentsubsidy
            where claim_id=${CLAIM}
            and rent_trans_id=${TRANS}
            \p\g
_END_
            read
            break
            ;;


            "Exit")
            exit 
            ;;


            *) 
            echo "ERROR: Invalid selection"
            ;;
            esac
        done


. $followUp
```

Each time an option is selected a function is called, the loop gets broken and the script moves on to a follow up action e.g. chooses another menu to run.

Please let me know if you want more of the whole script

thanks

Comment: Too many unknowns at this point, eg: is this code snippet wrapped in a larger while loop? what's happening in the subordinate code ($paramset, @transChange, @subsChange, menuSelect.sh, menu1.sh) called by all of those source (`.`) operations? are you really breaking out to the topmost level or is one of those subordinate calls invoking this code snippet (ie, adding another level to the call tree)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There are no loops anywhere in the script other than the 2 menus , ( I've posted the shorted of the 2 menus ).

Comment: Don't use `source` to jump back to your menu. Each menu action can be a separate script, but it should return instead of sourcing your menu script again

Comment: Are the menus in separate scripts and if so, what are the names of the scripts? A looping construct doesn't necessarily have to be a 'select'\'while' loop, you can get into a loop when 2 scripts take turns calling each other, eg, `menu1` calls `menu2` which calls `menu1` which calls `menu2` which ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There are no loops anywhere in the script other than the 2 menus , ( I've posted the shorted of the 2 menus ).  The paramset function lets the user input fresh variable values for hbdb, CLAIM, TRANS and SUBS, subsChange lets the user just change variable SUBS, menuSelect will load up either menu1 (posted above) or menu2 depending on variable values. menu1 loads the menu above.  None of the functions called by the menu will call the menu loop directly, it sets the followUp variable which only gets called after the menu loop is broken

Comment: Hi, to reference the extra points made:  1. "don't use source to jump back to your menu"....   The sourced snippet does not directly call a menu, it updates the followUp variable which is called after the menu loop breaks.    2. "are the menus in separate scripts?"....  yes they are menu1.sh and menu2.sh.   I see what you mean about getting into a loop situation without a select/while etc.  I just can't find where I've made that happen and I can't really post the entire thing

Comment: some simple debugging may help, eg, add `echo "entering script xyz"` and `echo "leaving script xyz"` at **every** entry/exit point in each script; the (obvious) downside to this method is that if you miss an entry/exit point then you won't get a complete picture of what's going on;also, it looks like you actually have 3 menu scripts ... menu1, menu2, menuSelect ... right?

Comment: @AndrewCourtenay Which script did you post? Is this `menuSelect.sh`? If so, do **not** source it from itself. Not even at the end.

Comment: Try a script recur with 2 lines: `printf "."; . ./recur`. Calling a menu from a menu from a menu from a menu is something like this.

Comment: Hi 'that other guy',  I posted menu1.sh.   So  'subsidy row details' ends with calling menu1 again. I see what you mean, menu1.sh is sourcing itself.  Is there a way to explain why that's bad? Intuitively it sounds terrible but I can't pin down the logic of it causing an issue

Comment: And sorry to 'that other guy' for not grasping your first comment, I'm with you now.  In the situations where I know I am going back to menu1 from menu1 I'll return the function rather than breaking and calling the menu again. Seems obvious now I say it

Comment: Still getting the error - I notice that the error comes the moment I call a menu option.   Is there a consequence to using source to much? Does it stack the if/else statements as permanent listeners for instance?

Comment: I've been researching recursion too deep errors - it looks like there is a limit (around 120) of recursions it permits before exiting.  It makes sense that my script is building up the recursions as it sources files, rather than there is a logic error causing an infinite loop, as it always takes time for the error to appear and it can appear on any menu option. I'm guessing that using functions running in subshells rather than sourcing would prevent this - but I don't think there is any other way to retrieve variables from functions run in external files...

Comment: I'm settling on the solution: Running the menu options where I don't need to access their variables in subshells, and hard coding the other functions in the menu itself so I don't need to use sourcing. Not very graceful but can't see any other solution

Comment: Actually I won't attempt that fix, as I've remembered I got the recursion error when I called a menu option that included no sourcing. So that scuppers my theory

Comment: Problem solved!  It does appear there is a limit on the number of times I can source a file - a file operator limit I think.  I've got round this by sourcing each file once at the beginning, putting the contents of each file into a function,  then calling the function names rather than repeatedly sourcing the files.

Comment: @AndrewCourtenay Please write your last comment as an answer and accept that. In that way everybody knows your question is answered. It is not cheating, SO wants you to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! It does appear there is a limit on the number of times I can source a file - a file operator limit I think. I've got round this by sourcing each file once at the beginning, putting the contents of each file into a function, then calling the function names rather than repeatedly sourcing the files.